# Make updated Int stay the same in a new struct

Tags: swiftui, struct, integer

I have a button that adds + 1 to an Int. I want to be able to access the value of the Int in another struct. Right now I am available to access the Int, but it starts from zero, not showing the amount of + 1 added after pressing the button in the previous struct.

Is there a way to "remember" the Ints that are added?

```
import SwiftUI

class NumberOrder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Number: Int = 0
}

struct Choose: View {
    
    @State var buttonClick: Bool = false
    
    @StateObject var numbeorder = NumberOrder()
    
    var body: some View {
     
      
        ZStack {
            
            Color.black
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("\(numbeorder.Number)")
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                
                Button {
                    buttonClick.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                }
                
                Button {
                    
                    self.numbeorder.Number += 1
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("ADD ONE")
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .medium))
                }
            }
            
            if buttonClick == true {
                Feeling1()
            }
        }

   }
}

struct Choose_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Choose()
    }
}


struct Feeling1: View {
    
    @State var goBack0: Bool = false
    
    @StateObject var numbeorder = NumberOrder()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

           Color.purple  
            
            Text("\(numbeorder.Number)")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
            
            Button {
                goBack0.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
            }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                .padding(.init(top: -250, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 150))
         
            
            
            if goBack0 == true {
                Choose()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're making a *new* instance of `NumberOrder`. You need to pass the instance you created to the new view.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any ideas on how to? @jnpdx

Comment: Do you know how to pass a parameter to a View? You would pass the instance of `NumberOrder` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different `@StateObject var numbeorder = NumberOrder()` that have no relations to each other.

Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Note, you should use the common practice to name your vars in lower case, particularly `Number`,
in `NumberOrder`, as Swift has already a `Number`.

So, in `Feeling1`, use `@ObservedObject var numbeorder: NumberOrder`
and use `Feeling1(numbeorder: numbeorder)` in `Choose`

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access, e.g.

```
struct Feeling1: View {
    
    // let goBack0: Bool // if only need read access
    @Binding var goBack0: Bool // if need read and write access
```

Note: don't use `@StateObject` unless you need a reference type instead of an `@State` struct which doesn't appear to be the case here, e.g.

```
struct NumberOrder {
    var number: Int = 0

    // mutating func someLogic() { }
}

@State var order = NumberOrder()
```